# Why do I get the error "'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint" for the this value of T?

Tags: typescript

In the code below, I get an error and don't understand why the error applies.

```js
class A {
    boop(): this {
        return this;
    }
}

class B {
    boop(): this {
        return this;
    }
}

function boopSnoot<T extends A | B>(snoot: T): T {
    return snoot.boop(); // error
}

function identity<T extends A | B>(snoot: T): T {
    return snoot; // no error
}
```

yields the error

```
'A | B' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'A | B'.
  Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'A' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'A | B'.
```

Not only is T guaranteed to be the exact same type that was passed in, no matter the subclass, it also returns the same exact object. Why does the error apply?

Comment: This is a good question; I think it's a limitation of TS not seeing the higher-order relationship between polymorphic `this` and the generic `T`.  I don't know how to get an authoritative source for this.  If you're interested in a workaround it might be [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NB4BkW), but that doesn't answer "why does the error apply" definitively.  I'll see if I can find any relevant github issues, when I get a chance

Comment: I haven't found anything obviously related except for maybe [ms/TS#33379](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33379). Maybe you want to file an issue in the TS github repo and ask what's going on here?  I expect it's something to do with the union-constrained object being widened to the union when indexing into it (as in [ms/TS#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181)) but I couldn't possibly say so authoritatively.  Anyway, good luck!